# Created a view but having permissions issue in SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database1 is having a table: A

```
Col1 Col2, Col3, Col4
 1    2      3     4
```

I want an user(XY) on Database2 to see the table, so i have created a view as

```
Create View vw_TableA as
    Select col1, col2, col3, col4
    from Database1.dbo.A
```

But the user is getting the error

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
>   The server principal "XY" is not able to access the database "Database1" under the current security context.

Working on: Sql Server 2008 R2
Script: TSql

Any ideas in giving permissions. I dont want to map the usre (XY) to the database1 because if i do that he get access to all the tables on database1.

This is only for one user at the moment but we going to get more users and more databases.

Is there a way of doing this.?

Comment: How can i specify db_changing option.?

Comment: I posted an answer based on my comment with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've granted permissions to the public role (not a good practice), users can only access objects in database1 if you've granted them permissions. Consequently, adding the user to database1 will allow only connect by default.

You could simply add the user (with no granted permissions) to database1 and turn on the `DB_CHANING` option in both databases. This is a viable solution from a security perspective as long as only the same privileged users can create objects in these databases (e.g. sysadmin role members).

```
ALTER DATABASE Database1 SET DB_CHAINING ON;
ALTER DATABASE Database2 SET DB_CHAINING ON;
```

Comment: @user9192401, did you add the user to Database1?

Comment: Yes. I have added the user to database1 and DB_Chaining set to on on both databases but still the user got the same error.

Comment: @user9192401, the 916 error specifically means the user doesn't have `CONNECT` permissions to the database referenced in the error message. This is granted by default of you simply executed `CREATE USER XY;`. I can't think of another reason why the user can't access the database.